# store key/value in NSDictionary/NSCache which retains data till the app is terminated

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have an app where i want to create a temporary cache which stores key and value.I have done the following

My code is : IN appDelegate.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *articleCache;
```

In appDelegate.m

```
@synthesize articleCache;
```

and i am calling it in viewController.m 
here i need to store the data so that it is cleared only when the app is terminated and is accessible anywhere in the app otherwise.
every time i visit an article i add it to the array so that next time i wont have to fetch it from the network thereby speed up the process.

the Problem is when i set the temp NSMutableDictionary the content gets added but for checkCache.articleCache i get nil.

```
#define DELEGATE ((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate])
```

this is my viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //[self loadfeeds];
    [self.activityIndi startAnimating];
    AppDelegate *checkCache = DELEGATE;
    NSString *link = self.webUrl;

//check if the article is already opened and cached before

    if([[checkCache.articleCache allKeys] containsObject:link])
    {
        NSLog(@"Key Exists");
        NSString *contents = [checkCache.articleCache valueForKey:link];
        [self loadDataOnView:contents];
    }
    else
    {
        NSOperationQueue* aQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        [aQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
            NSLog(@"Key not Exists");
            [self startParsing];
        }];
    } 
}
```

In parser method at the end i do the following i.e to store the article..
but if i add it directly to the checkCache.articleCache nothing is added what should i do?? but it gets added to temp.. do i access the articleCache incorrectly??

```
AppDelegate *checkCache = DELEGATE;
NSMutableDictionary *temp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [checkCache.articleCache setObject:Content forKey:url];
    [temp setObject:Content forKey:url];
```

So how can i solve it??
or Suggest me how can i use NSCache for the same problem. thanks a lot.
It might be a silly question but i m quite new to ios thanks.

Comment: you can use NSUserDefault

Comment: That code makes no sense.  `checkCache` is your AppDelegate, which doesn't have a `url` property to be set.  Then you're creating a temp dictionary, which is probably thrown away, but you don't give any context as to where that code is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In App delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.articleCache = [NSMutableDictionary new];
return YES;
}
```

When you have to set the object in cache.

```
AppDelegate *checkCache = DELEGATE;
[checkCache.articleCache setObject:obj forKey:@"Key1"];
```

To get the object back:

```
AppDelegate *checkCache = DELEGATE;
id obj = [checkCache.articleCache objectForKey:@"Key1"];
```

Though there are better ways to get this done.

Comment: better ways means?? like using NSCache??
by the way are there any disadvantages to storing variables in app delegate like this??? and since i m calling the AppDelegate *checkCache twice in the same class will it create 2 instances of appdelegate object???
because when i did that i could only store 1 article... if i visited the some other page the previously visited page contents are gone....

Comment: App delegate is singleton, so you can't create two instances. And yes this is not a clean approach of doing things. You should have singleton class which manages cache for you, app delegate is not a place to hold on to cache. But yes these things will come to you with experience.

Comment: so ill need to create something like a data model class??
can u give me a small example in code if possible?? or any reference that would help me??
and thanks a lot :) appreciate your help

Comment: And DONT set a new dictionary to cache everytime you have to insert something in cache

Comment: i had not done this self.articleCache = [NSMutableDictionary new];
in my appDelegate.h... that is the reason it wasnt working....
now it works fine... thanks a lot.
i thought after we synthesize the property we dont need to create a new object of articleCache.. so hadnt done that...

Comment: @sythesize only binds variables to properties, but you also have alloc memory to variable. By the way you don't have to synthesize anymore. It is an older practice.